# Basic ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, mongoose, ejs

I am a new bie of NodeJS. I am writing a simple application with a database integration.

For Rendering i used ejs template engine to render. upto now everything working fine. succeeded in few steps as follows,

DB Integration with mongoose.
Data retrieval by avoiding routes

Finally i want to display a list on users page which is coded like wise,

app.js

```
   app.get('/users', function(req, res){
User.find({},function (err, users) {
    console.log(users)
    res.render('users', { title: 'Users', users : users });
});
    console.log(users)
  });
```

users.html

```
       <ul>
           <% for(var i=0; i<users.length; i++) { %>
            <li><%=i%><%=JSON.stringify(users[i]) %></li>
           <% } %>
       </ul>
```

I need a an output something coded like this: but showing undefined.

```
      <ul>
           <% for(var i=0; i<users.length; i++) { %>
        <li><%=i%><%=users[i].name %></li>
        <% } %>
        </ul>
```

Can anyone suggest what would be the mistake.  i am unable to print the name.

Comment: What does the `JSON.stringify(users[i])` output?

Comment: Is `users[i]` a json string or is it actually an object (check with `typeof users[i]`)?

Comment: Hi mscdex,                                                                            <ul id="usersli">
  <% users.forEach(function(user){ %>
   <li><%= user %> &lt;<%= user.age %>&gt;</li>
  <% }) %>
</ul>            Giving O/p : { _id: 534e4421e0035316b849d038, name: 'ayyappa', age: 26, status: 'Active' } <undefined>